# can i call function in my wordpress plugin when sending publish post in every plugin or user?

Tags: wordpress, hook

i want to call my function when user or admin or another plugin sending publish post.

any hook exist for this ?
i try some hook like publish_post.

but this work just if i put my code in that plugin which sending post.

i want my plugin Independent and when sending post in any plugin or admin or every where .... , my function in my plugin do something.

this is for SEO reason and its hard to say why i want do this.

some code i write

```
function post_published_notification($post) {

$ID= $post->ID;
 $my_post = array(
            'ID'           => $ID,
            'post_title'     => "anything"
            );
       wp_update_post( $my_post );
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

There's are hook called `save_post` - `do_action( 'save_post', $post_ID, $post, $update );`. You could check if `$post->post_status` is set to published and maybe keep your own record of whether it's had the published status before.

Example on how to use it:

```
function post_published_notification( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    if ( $post->post_status == 'publish' && ! get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'published_notification_set', true ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'published_notification_set', 1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: i use  do_action( 'save_post', "post_published_notification");
function post_published_notification( $post ) { .....  .can you give me some example code @MSTannu?

Comment: You need to use `add_action` to attach your function. I've edited to include an example.